# How does *max_element() work in this snippet?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

```
int N = 6;
vector< vector<int> > A(N, vector<int>(3));

/* Do operation with A */

cout<<(*max_element(a.begin(),a.end()))[2]<<endl;
```

I am not sure what does `max_element` is doing here. Can anybody help in understanding this?

PS: I came across this while reviewing [indy256](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=MemberProfile&cr=22708888) 's solution in the TopCoder practice room, while solving [this](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=3556&rd=6538) problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lexicographicaly comparing (because the elements are vectors), `max_element` finds the largest element in the vector `a`. It returns an iterator that's immediately dereferenced, giving a reference to the element. It then calls calls `operator[]`, giving back the element at index 2 that's ultimately streamed to `cout`.

A less terse equivalent would be:

```
auto it = max_element(a.begin(), a.end());
int i = (*it)[2]; // better make sure the vector has at least 3 elements!

cout << i;
```